# How to cast an int into a nullable type?

Tags: c#

I'm just doing simple int swap program. I also just learnt about casting so I'm trying it out in this program. But I'm getting an error that says I should do an explicit cast.

I don't think I understand the concept of casts. What's the problem?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the FIRST Integer.");
    string tempint1 = Console.ReadLine();
    int int1 = Convert.ToInt32(tempint1);

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the SECOND Integer.");
    string tempint2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int int2 = Convert.ToInt32(tempint2);

    Console.WriteLine();

    int? swapInt = null;
    swapInt = (int)int1;
    int1 = int2;
    int2 = swapInt;

    Console.WriteLine("The integers have been swapped!");
    Console.WriteLine("The FIRST INTEGER is now " + int1);
    Console.WriteLine("The SECOND INTEGER is now " + int2);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: int1 is already int why are you casting it again??

Comment: You should tell in question where the error is.

Comment: Why even use a nullable `int?` in this case anyway?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `I also just learnt about casting so I'm trying it out`

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, the typically way to perform a swap would be to use a temp variable of the exact same type... `int temp = int1; int1 = int2; int2 = temp;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`swapInt` is a nullable int and below:

you try to assign an nullable int to an int that's the problem:

```
int2 = swapInt;
```

If you change it to to the following one it would be ok,

```
int2 = swapInt.Value;
```

Furthermore, this piece of code:

```
int? swapInt = null;
swapInt = (int)int1;
int1 = int2;
int2 = swapInt;
```

it could be changed to the following one:

```
 int? swapInt = int1;
 int1 = int2;
 int2 = swapInt.Value;
```

You don't have to cast an already integer to an int, `(int)int1;`

**Update**

I have to make a few comments about your program, which you could take them into acount.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the users input.

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the FIRST Integer.");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the SECOND Integer.");
    string b = Console.ReadLine();

    // Variables, in which we will store the parsed strings that user passes.
    int integerA;
    int integerB;

    // Try to parse the strings that user passes to create two integer numbers.
    // If either parse of a or parse of b fail, then the method Int32.TryParse()
    // will return false and the code in the body of if, will not be executed.
    if(Int32.TryParse(a, out integerA) && Int32.TryParse(b, out integerB))
    {
        // Pass the integers to the methods called swap
        Swap(ref integerA, ref integerB);
        Console.WriteLine("The integers have been swapped!");
        Console.WriteLine("The FIRST INTEGER is now " + int1);
        Console.WriteLine("The SECOND INTEGER is now " + int2);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

// This methods makes the actual swap
static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

If you read carefully the above code, then you will have noticed that we don't make use of nullables and actually, we don't need them at this case.

For your information, there is a *generic*  method in C#, which can be used for swapping to objects either they are numbers or not. This method's name is `Swap` and it's signature is the following:

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
```

You can use this method as below:

```
Swap<int>(ref integerA, ref integerB);
```

For more information about this method, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

> What's `ref` stands for ?

As it is stated in `MSDN`:

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument variable in the calling method. The value of a reference parameter is always the same as the value of the underlying argument variable.

Example let that we have a method called `Increment`:

```
public void Increment(int x)
{
    // This will increase the value of variable x by one.
    // This change is only visible insied the body of this method
    // and it is not reflected outside of it.
    x++;
}
```

If we had defined the method as below:

```
public void Increment(ref int x)
{
    x++;
}
```

the change in the value of `x` would have been visible also outside of the body of the method called `Increment`.

> Why so?

Because in the first case we pass a **copy** of the value that is stored in `x`, while in the second case we don't pass a **copy** of this value. Hence any changes in the second case will be reflected also outside of the body of the method called `Incerement`.

Comment: Christos, thank you. I haven't learned refs yet so I don't know what they do. Could you explain?

Comment: @Code_Steel of course I can explaing what they do. Please see my update in a few minutes. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @Code_Steel please have a look at my update and let me know if that's clear.

Comment: Christos, thank you. It is clear but I need to think about it more.

Comment: @Code_Steel you welcome dude. if you have any more questions about it, please feel free to post it and someone else or me, if we can help, we will do so.

Answer (score 6):

`int?` is a shorthand for a type called `Nullable<int>`. Obviously, then, `int` and `Nullable<int>` aren't the same type. `Nullable<int>` has a property called `Value` and that property is the actual `int`. To access the `Value` property, you should first check whether the `HasValue` property is `true` (just as you would check whether a reference type is not `null`).

Here's the problem, now:

There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `Nullable<int>` (remember, that's the same as `int?`) and that conversion says that a new `Nullable<int>` is created, with `HasValue` set to `true` and its `Value` set to the value of the initial `int`. Thus, you are allowed to do:

```
int a = 5
int? b = 5; // implicit conversion
int? c = a; // implicit conversion
int? d = c;
```

On the other hand, the opposite conversion, from `Nullable<int>` to `int` doesn't exist implicitly, because the `Nullable<int>` may have its `HasValue` property set to `false`, which means that a regular `int` won't be able to describe it and the compiler doesn't know what you'd want to happen in this case. So, this is why you can't do:

```
int? a = 5;
int b = a; // illegal, no implicit conversion exists
```

Instead, you'd want to do something like this:

```
int? a = 5;
if(a.HasValue)
{
    int b = a.Value;
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Casts aren't related to the question (it's just a suggestion by the compiler, but it's not actually what you'd want to do here). For the sake of learning: a cast is simply an instruction to the compiler to treat an expression of one type as an expression of another (hopefully compatible) type, possibly by applying a conversion between those two types (if such a conversion is defined anywhere).

Comment: Nice to see an answer that includes some detailed and useful explanation. Might I suggest also provide a working code sample too for completeness

Comment: Yes, please add code to help me understand.

There are many answers here. Can I still experiment with nullable int in this question or should I use an swapint of type int?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is **no implicit conversion** from `int?` to `int`. Since `int?` can be null, compiler doesn't allow that, it wants from you to perform the cast explicitly:

```
int2 = (int) swapInt;
```

By doing this you are telling the compiler "*I know what I'm doing.*", if the `swapInt` is null this will throw exception at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You problem is in this line

```
int2 = swapInt;
```

`int2` is an `integer` and `swapInt` is a `nullable int` or `null?`. You cannot assign like that because compiler cannot directly convert `null?` to `null`. Hence the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

When it cannot do so it asks for you to convert it.

So Change

```
int2 = swapInt;
```

to

```
if (swapInt.HasValue)
    int2 = swapInt.Value;
```

**Nullable Types**

Value types like `int` cannot be null. Nullable types are types which store value types and can be null.

To extract value from them first check whether they have value. This is done be checking `HasValue`. It returns a boolean and if it is true, we extract value using `swapInt.Value`.

You can cast like `(int)swapInt` but then it will throw exception if it does not have any value.

You can cast or get its value. Performance for both is same as cast is syntactic sugar for the Value property.

Comment: Or you can cast it, just to point out that the compiler error isn't *completely* stupid :)

Comment: It's not wise to use `Value` without checking is it `HasValue` first... I think that's quite an important point to be clear on for someone who is still learning the basics

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Yeah, you got a +1 for that, I don't know where you got the -1(s).

Answer (score -1):

`swapInt` is a nullable type, the method `GetValueOrDefault` returns the value if not null else default value of the underlying type

`int2 = swapInt.GetValueOrDefault()`